# Audio not playing until moving the camera away from Qr code - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, avaudioplayer

I am new to `iOS` `development` and I am developing an app in which I want to play some audios when the `QR code` gets detected. I am able to detect the `QR code` and also play the audios but the thing is the audio-only plays when I move the camera away from `QR code`. So, if I am pointing the camera towards `QR code` it does not play the audio but as soon as I move the camera (i.e. no `QR code` is getting detected) the audio starts playing. I don't want this behavior I want audio to play as soon as `QR code` gets detected. Any suggestion would be great as I have just started `iOS` `development` 2 3 days back. Thanks.

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{



NSString *detected=@"";



if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {



    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];



    if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {


        detected=[NSString stringWithString:[metadataObj stringValue]];

        NSString *path =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cbp"  ofType:@"mp3"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];



        _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];


        [_audioPlayer play];


    }



}
```

}

Comment: Which library you are using for detecting the QR code? it's better if you can add the code in the question body.

Comment: I am just using AVFoundation.framework. Sure I add the code

Comment: @RaviSharma I have added the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't initialise the `AVAudioPlayer` in this `AVFoundation` delegate method, Load the player with sound file before scanning start.

```
(void)loadSound{
    NSString *beepFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cbp" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL URLWithString:beepFilePath];
    NSError *error;

    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:beepURL error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Could not play sound file.");
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

You can call `loadSound()` function in `viewWillAppear()` method.And your `AVFoundation` delegate method will look like this:-

```
(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
NSString *detected=@"";

if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {

    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {
        detected=[NSString stringWithString:[metadataObj stringValue]];    

        if (_audioPlayer) {
            [_audioPlayer play];
        }
    }
}
}
```

try this.